# Ordering a list by suming several rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have class like this:

```
public class UserDataPoint
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Spend { get; set; }

    public UserDataPoint(string strUser, string strCategory, int intSpend)
    {
        User = strUser;
        Category = strCategory;
        Spend = intSpend;
    }
}
```

Which is populated with data like this:

```
var myList = new List<UserDataPoint>() { 
    new UserDataPoint("Bob", "Local", 34),
    new UserDataPoint("Bob", "National", 16),
    new UserDataPoint("Bob", "Mobile", 7),
    new UserDataPoint("John", "Local", 18),
    new UserDataPoint("Fred", "National", 22),
    new UserDataPoint("Fred", "International", 65) };
```

I'd like to populate an array:

```
UserDataPoint[] myArray;
```

With the data from myList, but ordered by 'User' with the highest *total* 'Spend'.  So from the example data above, Fred would be first in the list (22 + 65 = 87), followed by Bob (34 + 16 + 7 = 57) and last of all John (18).

So my resulting array would be populated in this order:

```
UserDataPoint[] myArray = new UserDataPoint[] { 
    new UserDataPoint("Fred", "National", 22),
    new UserDataPoint("Fred", "International", 65),
    new UserDataPoint("Bob", "Local", 34),
    new UserDataPoint("Bob", "National", 16),
    new UserDataPoint("Bob", "Mobile", 7),        
    new UserDataPoint("John", "Local", 18) };
```

How can I implement a LINQ statement to perform this ordering on myList to give me myArray?

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UserDataPoint[] myArray =
    myList.GroupBy(udp => udp.User)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(udp => udp.Spend))
            .SelectMany(g => g)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: You should use OrderByDescending. If you use OrderBy, then the user 'John' is the first element in the array.